# Radio Button not Working in ie

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 4 radio button in my form, once i submit the form any of the radio button should checked, if not a alert message will be displayed. its working properly in chrome, firefox, but in ie one i checked the radion it always showing the alert so i cant submit the form, i have given my code below please help me

PHP:

```
<form action="user_register.php" method="POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>USERNAME:</label></td>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="regtext" required/>
    <label>RESIDING CITY:</label></td>
    <input type="text" name="city" class="regtext" required/>
    <label>I'M A</label>
    <label>ARTIST &nbsp <input type="radio" value="1" name="user_type" >    </label>&nbsp
    <label>MODEL &nbsp <input type="radio" value="2" name="user_type"></label>&nbsp
    <label>COMPOSER &nbsp <input type="radio" value="3" name="user_type" ></label>&nbsp<br>
    <label>BEAT MAKER &nbsp <input type="radio" value="4" name="user_type" ></label>&nbsp
    <label>NONE &nbsp <input type="radio" value="0" name="user_type" ></label>
    <label> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="letter" > &nbsp  I WOULD LIKE TO RECEIVE YOUR NEWSLETTER</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mainhead">
        <input type="submit" name="register" class="submit" value="SEND AND REGISTER NOW">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var province = document.forms["myForm"]["province"].value;
        if (province == 0 ) {
            alert("Select Province");
            document.myForm.province.focus() 
            return false;
        }
        var user_type = document.forms["myForm"]["user_type"].value;
        if (user_type == null || user_type == "") {
            alert("Select Who You are");
            return false;
        }
        var letter = document.forms["myForm"]["letter"].value;
        if (letter == null || letter == "") {
            alert("Select that you want to receive news letter");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no element having name as `province`

Comment: @Rayon Dabre, that does'nt matter. i need only abour the user_type and its validation

Comment: Your html is not valid. Maybe there is the problem. Remove `</td>` in line 2 and 4. Also remove `</div>` in line 13.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that for IE, `document.forms["myForm"]["user_type"]` is an HTMLCollection and has no `value`

Solution is to change

`var user_type = document.forms["myForm"]["user_type"].value;`

to

`var user_type = document.querySelector('form[name="myForm"] input[name="user_type"]:checked').value;`

Comment: Not validating in chrome also

Comment: Did you change province to city? That DOES matter.

Answer (score 0):

What i observed is :

No name `province` present in code (what you gave). If you include it here, it will not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var province = document.forms["myForm"]["province"].value;
    if (province == 0 ) {
        alert("Select Province");
        document.myForm.province.focus() 
        return false;
    }
    var user_type = document.forms["myForm"]["user_type"].value;
        if (user_type == null || user_type == "") {
        alert("Select Who You are");
        return false;
    }
    var letter = document.forms["myForm"]["letter"].value;
        if (letter == null || letter == "") {
        alert("Select that you want to receive news letter");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

After removing `province` validation. It started working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {

    var user_type = document.forms["myForm"]["user_type"].value;
        if (user_type == null || user_type == "") {
        alert("Select Who You are");
        return false;
    }
    var letter = document.forms["myForm"]["letter"].value;
        if (letter == null || letter == "") {
        alert("Select that you want to receive news letter");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

So, as **Mr Rayon Dabre** said "*There is no element having name as province*". So, i also agree with him. Remove `province` validation from **validateForm()** function (as it is not used in `<from></form>`)

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

```
function validateForm() {

    var user_type = document.getElementsByName('user_type');
    var u_type = '';

    for (var i = 0, length = user_type.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (user_type[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
            u_type = user_type[i].value;

            // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
            break;
        }
    }

    if (u_type == "") {
        alert("Select Who You are");
        return false;
    }
    var letter = document.getElementsByName('letter')[0].checked;

    if (letter == "" || letter == undefined) {
        alert("Select that you want to receive news letter");
        return false;
    }
}
```